# Qmediaplayer setposition QtPython

Tags: python, qt

I am trying to set up a simple media player with Qt.

I want to choose the start position of the video on startup of the player. I bound this to an isSeekable event to make sure media is loaded and seekable.

Still the player does not work as expected. Either I am gettings errors (0xC00D6D60) or the video just starts from the beginning.

This is my code:

```
def seekable_changed(self, is_seekable):
     if (is_seekable):
        self._player.pause()
        self._player.setPosition(videostartmsdiff) # milliseconds
        self._player.play()
```

I tried different combinations with or without pause() and play()

How do I set start position in Qt to let it work as expected?
Thanks

Comment: Hi fwerre, did you solve this problem? I have a quite same question except I'm working on an audio player.

Comment: Are you using PyQt or PySide and which version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You should connect to `QMediaPlayer::stateChanged(QMediaPlayer::State state)` signal and call `setPosition` when `state` becomes `QMediaPlayer::PlayingState`.

Comment: In fact, I need to wait for both Signals `isSeekable()` and `state == QMendiaPlayer::PlayingState` before calling `setPosition()`. What I did not find is wether I must always `pause()` before setting Position or which is the correct way to do it?

Comment: still getting that "serious media error" 0xC00D6D60 depending on where I jump to...

Comment: Can you please update the question and add [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?